# key value template loop with equals

Tags: django, dictionary, templates

I am trying to hide div based on the 1 and 0. I wrote the below code but I am getting Exception Value:'int' object is not iterable  error. I think I am doing wrong with {%if k.v == 1%} but don't know how to fix.

hide_dict items -->  `{'hide0': 1, 'hide1': 0, 'hide2': 0, 'hide3': 1}`

```
{% for key, values in hide_dict.items %}
    {% for mydict in values %}
        {%for k,v in mydict.items %}
            {%if k.v == 1%}
                <div style="display:none">
            {% elif k.v == 0 %}
                <div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "k,v" in the for loop stands for "key, value". The numbers you need - 1 and 0 - are the value in that case. You can access them by using only `v` instead of `k.v`. Also because you point to "hide_dict" you must be using "key, values" as for the first loop you made. So try to use `{%if values == 1%}` instead of `{%if k.v == 1%}`, same applies for the `elif` statement.